# Why is ~/.config or ~/.bashrc considered a directory in bash?

Tags: bash

We were assigned a project that works with various file. The code in question is this:

```
if [[ -f $first_arg ]]; then
    open_file $first_arg
elif [[ -d $first_arg ]]; then
    search_directory $first_arg
.....
```

It works fine with just regular files, but it comes into the second condition if I run the script like this (with the ~/.) :

```
./script01.sh ~/.config
```

So I'm wondering what goes on when bash checks -f and -d, what is considered a directory or file and what is not anymore.

Comment: Are you sure `.config` isn't a directory?

Comment: No, it is a file, when I use `vim ~/.config` it opens up the file without any problem

Comment: `vim` can edit directories. What does `file ~/config` say? (It's a directory on my Ubuntu system, created when I set up my account.) And why did you mention `~/.bashrc`? Does your script think it's a directory too?

Comment: what does `ls -ld ~/.config` show?

Comment: `.config` usually *is* a directory; its purpose is to store configuration files for applications following the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.config` is quite commonly a directory as Joe has suggested in the comments.

As to what goes on, bash apparently calls `stat(2)` on the file in question which returns a corresponding structure including `st_mode` field. Details for that are in `inode(7)`:

```
The stat.st_mode field (for statx(2), the  statx.stx_mode  field)  con‐
tains the file type and mode.
```

Namely:

```
The following mask values are defined for the file type:
...
    S_IFREG    0100000   regular file
    ...
    S_IFDIR    0040000   directory
```

All that is left is to check which bits are set.